# Partitioning an Infinite Set Using Natural Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Can we partition all positive real numbers that are greater or equal to one, i.e. $[1, \infty)$ into sets of $[n, n+1)$ such that $n$ is a natural number?

Intuitively it is obviously correct but is there a way to prove it by using archimedean property?

Answer (score 1):

Assume 1 <= r.  Prove B = { n in N : r < n } is non empty.
Next show B has minimum element.  Call that integer n.
As 1 <= r < n, conclude 1 <= n-1 <= r < n.